# Organising Imports in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, editing, netbeans6.5

Netbeans is able to organise imports in a similar fashion to eclipse, but:

- it seems unable to remove unused imports for classes that can't be resolved (and are no longer used)
- I can only organise one class at a time - eclipse allows import organisation on packages and projects etc.

Is there some way that I can fix these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently upgraded to Netbeans 6.7 and "fix imports" works the same as it did in 6.5.  I'm not sure why this does not remove unresolved imports.  I have been unable to find a bug case about this.

As far a getting "Fix Imports" to work for multiple classes, that is planned for Netbeans 6.8.

[Planning for NetBeans 6.8](http://wiki.netbeans.org/EditorPlan68) under the Java section.

> (E) Format code and fix imports on
>   multiple files (code beautifier) (Max
>   10)