# netbeans: how to determine unused JARs?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Over the course of developing my Spring MVC project, I've accumulated an overabundance of JARs, many of which I suspect are no longer necessary.

I see that Eclipse has a plugin that can help find [unused JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248589/finding-unused-jars-used-in-an-eclipse-project)s.  Is there an equivalent for Netbeans or something that works on the command line?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this can be done in a reliable way.

What if you have classes that are loaded via reflection?
What if you have classes that are only referenced from within a Spring XML file?

They will never show up in the Java source code

Answer (score 1):

A good command line tool would be [Tattletale](http://jboss.org/tattletale/)

You can check other recommendations here:
[How to Determine which JARs are Used in an Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222809/how-to-determine-which-jars-are-used-in-an-application)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Netbeans has an inbuilt function for that? "Remove unused dependencies" it is called iirc.

Well, that works for a single file. If you want more than one, 6.8 should add that according to [Organising Imports in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164578/organising-imports-in-netbeans)